# jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).ionRangeSlider is not a function TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, import, bundle

I'm trying to import ionrangeslider on my bundle.js but having issue importing and using it here's my code.

`npm install ion-rangeslider --save-prod`

header.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import ionRangeSlider from 'ion-rangeslider';
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".hamburger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
      });
    
      $(".wpcf7-form-control-wrap.InvestmentRange input").ionRangeSlider();
    });
    
    $(window).on('load',function() {
        // Animate loader off screen
        $(".preloader").fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

bundle.js

```
import './components/header.js';
import './components/carousel.js';
import '../../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js';
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import '../../node_modules/ion-rangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.js';
```

gulpfile.babel.js

```
export const scripts = () => {
  return src(['src/js/bundle.js'])
  .pipe(named())
  .pipe(webpack({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    mode: PRODUCTION ? 'production' : 'development',
    devtool: !PRODUCTION ? 'inline-source-map' : false,
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js'
    },
  }))
  .pipe(dest('dist/js'));
}
```

I'm still new to webpack and this is my first time working on it hopefully someone can help me thanks

Comment: I don't think the plugin `ionRangeSlider` supports ES Modules. It looks like it modifies the global `$` variable.

Comment: can you post your webpack configuration please?